# Repulsive gravity formulation: a query

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, cosmology, lagrangian-formalism

I was going through this arxiv paper by Magnano: [gr-qc/9312008](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9312008)
For modeling non linear and repulsive gravity he takes the generic lagrangian $$L = f(R)\sqrt{-g}.$$

Varying this $L$ with $g^{\mu\nu}$, I get
$$f'(R)R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}f(R)g_{\mu\nu} =0.$$

But he gets additional terms. His equation being,
$$f'(R)R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}f(R)g_{\mu\nu} -\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}f'(R) + g_{\mu\nu}\square f'(R) =0;$$

where $\square = g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}$.

How are these additional terms with $\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}$ and $\square$  obtained? Any ideas?

Comment: You would need to show your own derivation to get a useful answer, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The correct derivation can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F(R)_gravity). Let me summarise it.

Starting from the $f(R)$ action, its variation reads:
$$\delta S=\int \sqrt{-g}\,\delta f(R)+f(R)\,\delta\sqrt{-g}$$
Of course $\delta f(R)=f'(R)\delta R$. The variation of the other term is
$$\delta \sqrt{-g}=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}\,g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}$$
just like in the standard derivation from the Einstein-Hilbert action. As for the variation of the Ricci scalar, one can say as usual:
$$\delta R = \delta (R_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu})=R_{\mu\nu}\, \delta g^{\mu\nu}+g^{\mu\nu} \,\delta R_{\mu\nu}=R_{\mu\nu}\,\delta g^{\mu\nu} + g_{\mu\nu}\square\, \delta g^{\mu\nu} -\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu \,\delta g^{\mu\nu}$$
The variation of the Ricci tensor is a bit tricky but still the same as in the usual derivation from the Einstein-Hilber action. Plugging everything in:
$$\delta S=\int \sqrt{-g}\,\left(f'(R)(R_{\mu\nu}\,\delta g^{\mu\nu} + g_{\mu\nu}\square\, \delta g^{\mu\nu} -\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu \,\delta g^{\mu\nu})-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}\,g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}\right)$$
Integrating by parts:
$$\delta S=\int \sqrt{-g}\,\left(f'(R)R_{\mu\nu}+ g_{\mu\nu}\square f'(R)-\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu f'(R)-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}\,g_{\mu\nu}\right)\delta g^{\mu\nu}$$
which is the equation in the paper mentioned by the OP.

It seems that the OP's mistake stems from believing that $\delta R = R_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}$, which is not the case.

Comment: Thanks John. So, in Einstein-Hilbert action, the delta(R) term leads to a total derivative  and the integral of the total derivative becomes 0 (as per wikipedia site). But in f(R) gravity, the delta(R) term does not boil down to a total derivative (due to the presence of f '(R) term). Hence it does not become 0.  Hope I understood it right.

Comment: @sgemc That's right!